# Problemas con SNMP para monitorizar squid proxy

Tags: proxy

tengo la siguiente pregunta, estoy configurando zabbix para monitorizar squid proxy, ya agregue en la configuracion del squid el puerto 3401, tmb cree las reglas de snmp comunity y snmp access, y ejecuto el netstat -tuln | grep 3401 para ver si esta permitiendo la comunicacion por upd a ese puerto, pero solo me arroja que esta permitiendo la comunicacion por udp6 mediante ese puerto, entonces pense si tengo que crear una iptable como la siguiente iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 3401 -j ACCEPT, para que tambien permite la comunicacion por udp para ipv4.

Ya que si puedo crear el host en zabbix y me aparece en status enable, pero el squid no me manda datos para poder monitorizarlo, ya que las graficas me aparecen en blanco, y comprobe los OID que maneja squid con las que estan en mi plantilla y son los mismo que tengo dados de alta, y el servido zabbix ejecuto el comando siguiente snmpwalk -v2c -c public ip_servidor_squid y me arroja informacion al igual que si agrego el puerto 161 al comando snmpwalk -v2c -c public ip_servidor_squid:161, pero si agrego el puerto 3401, no me arroja nada, sera que tambien deba de agregar una iptable para el puerto 3401 al igual que el servidor proxy squid.